# Create an ODBC Connection via the Command Line on a Mac

Tags: macos, odbc, driver, command-line-interface, filemaker

I'm working on a Mac with a FileMaker ODBC Driver

I've successfully created new ODBC connections via this method:
- open ODBC Manager
- switch to system DSN tab
- click add
- select FileMaker ODBC driver
- enter details (nickname, host, database)

How can I accomplish the same workflow via the command line on my mac?

My ideal pseudocode looks something like this:
install_new_odbc_connection(nickname, host, database)

I've found a similar discussion for windows:
[Install An ODBC connection from cmd line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13433371/install-an-odbc-connection-from-cmd-line)

And here's a page which suggests that I might be able to edit some ini files directly, but I'm not sure how to do this:
http://hiltmon.com/blog/2013/09/18/setup-odbc-for-r-on-os-x/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on your ODBC Management software. If you use "ODBC Manager" from http://www.odbcmanager.net/index.php you can modify the file directly through the bash:

/Library/ODBC/odbc.ini

Based on this article:

https://web.archive.org/web/20131007145001/https://www.jonathanstark.com/blog/setting-up-odbc-for-mysql-on-a-mac

Comment: Some tips: 1. Edit the `odbc.ini` file directly. Much more stable than using iODBC Administrator. 2. You don't need to specify the username or password in the `odbc.ini` connection. When connecting, use the username and password of a valid MySQL user. 3. You should specify the `Database` key in the connection.