# Change ODBC in command line (Win. 7)

Tags: command-line, odbc, command-prompt

I have a set of ODBCs that have to be changed each time I move a computer from one domain to the other. I have move a bunch of them so I am looking for a way to do this with command line to save time. If you know any faster ways of doing this I am open to this also.

Answer (score 0):

You can change from cmd as below.

```
odbcconf configsysdsn "MySQL ODBC 5.2w Driver"
"DSN=test;SERVER=127.0.0.1;PORT=3306;DATABASE=mdb;UID=root
```

Reference: [Install An ODBC connection from cmd line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13433371/install-an-odbc-connection-from-cmd-line)

Comment: Please, [format](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) your answer. It is difficult to read.

Comment: That's not going to work. There are things missing here.